# cannot get this code to compile

Tags: compiling

Can I please get advice on how to get this code to compile.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

\title{Paper about large cardinals}

\author[$\mathrm{M^{\lowercase{c}}Callum}$ ]{\textbf{Rupert} 

$\mathbf{M^{\lowercase{c}}Callum}$ }

\begin{abstract}

In previous work... 

\end{abstract}

 \maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M\textsuperscript{c}` more natural than using,  math fonts. the error  in `\maketitle` is because  you have a paragraph break between first and second name in `\author`, delete the blank line.

Comment: somewhat off-topic ... you're using `amsart`, which incorporates `amsthm` and loads `amsmath` and `amsfonts`, so you don't have to `\usepackage` for those.  however, it doesn't load `amssymb`, so you will have to load that explicitly if you need access to the symbol names.